# Plymouth theme does not show up ever

Tags: boot, plymouth

I have a problem, that Plymouth booting theme never shows up. Nor default one, nor custom installed.

I tried installing custom theme & executing following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives -config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

`dmidecode` output

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: F5
    Release Date: 06/19/2014
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6
```

My GPU: Geforce 750

Also I have `quiet splash` enabled.

I only got a booting screen once, when I was starting Ubuntu live environment.
This happens not only on Ubuntu, but in other distros.

May the problem be in bios or something else?

EDIT: **Switching to nouveau driver brings splash screen back.**

Problem still not solved.

Comment: Should your title really be: **Plymouth splash doesn't show up when nVidia drivers used**?

Comment: Maybe it should, but I just found out it now